# How would i retrieve the postal code from an xml response from google geocoding api?

Tags: model-view-controller, google-api, geocoding

Im currently working on an MVC project and need to get the postal code based on the users address. I have been able to successfully get the latitude and longitude but can't figure out how to extract the postal code from the xml response.

Here is the XML im working with which is the sample XML they use on the api documentation page.

```
 <GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>street_address</type>
  <formatted_address>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>1600</long_name>
   <short_name>1600</short_name>
   <type>street_number</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Amphitheatre Pkwy</long_name>
   <short_name>Amphitheatre Pkwy</short_name>
   <type>route</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Mountain View</long_name>
   <short_name>Mountain View</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>San Jose</long_name>
   <short_name>San Jose</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Santa Clara</long_name>
   <short_name>Santa Clara</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>California</long_name>
   <short_name>CA</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United States</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>94043</long_name>
   <short_name>94043</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>37.4217550</lat>
    <lng>-122.0846330</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>37.4188514</lat>
     <lng>-122.0874526</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>37.4251466</lat>
     <lng>-122.0811574</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA</place_id>
  >plus_code<
   >global_code<849VCWC8+W5>/global_code<
   >compound_code<CWC8+W5 Mountain View, California, United States>/compound_code<
 >/plus_code<
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Here is my code in the Controller that I am using to get the information:

```
    string address = "Users Address(HIDDEN)";

    string requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false&key=HIDDEN", address);

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

    document.Load(requestUri);

    string status = document.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/status").InnerText;
    string lat = "", lng = "", postal = "";

    if (status == "OK")
    {
        lat = document.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat").InnerText;
        lng = document.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng").InnerText;
        postal = document.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component/long_name").InnerText;
    }

    return ($"Latitude: {lat} / Longitude: {lng} / {postal}");
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been doing some more digging and found the answer out. Basically had to iterate through the address_component nodes until i get to the postal_code child node of the address_component and get the long_name child node which has the postal. Here is my solution:

```
XmlNodeList nlist = document.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component");

                foreach(XmlNode node in nlist)
                {
                    var longName = node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText;
                    var shortName = node.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText;
                    var zipType = node.ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText;

                    if(zipType == "postal_code")
                    {
                        postal = longName;
                    }
                }
```